# React Native Error on building Expo Project

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, node-modules

i have a create-react-native-app Application with Expo and want to install the node module react-native-appearance to switch the App-Theme based on OS Settings.

Here is my code from App.js

```
import React from "react";
import AppContainer from "./navigation/navigation";
import { AppearanceProvider, useColorScheme } from "react-native-appearance";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let theme = useColorScheme();
    return (
      <AppearanceProvider>
        <AppContainer theme={theme} />
      </AppearanceProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the Error:

```
While trying to resolve module 'react-native-appearance' from file **/**/**/App.js, the 
package **/**/**//node_modules/react-native-appearance/package.json` was successfully 
found. However, this package itself specifies a `main`module field that could not be 
resolved (`/***/****/****/****/****/****/node_modules/react-native- 
appearance/src/index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

/Users/mbolender/Productive/project/frontend/frontend/node_modules/
react-native-appearance/src/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|
.jsx|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.scss|.ios.sass|.native.sass|.sass|.ios.json|.native.json|.json
/Users/mbolender/Productive/project/frontend/frontend/node_modules/react-native-appearance
/src/index/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|
.jsx|.ios.scss|.native.scss|.sass.ios.json|.native.json|.json
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
```

And i already followed the solution to delete ./node_modules + close expo builder and re-install ./node_modules. But it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

All the expo managed projects need to install expo supported packages by using `expo install` else if you have a bare app you can use `npm i`.

Foy your case try this:

`npm uninstall react-native-appearance`

`expo install react-native-appearance`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I deinstalled `react-native-appearance` and did `expo install react-native-appearance`. But the same error appears